# Trigger Flow - Scheduled Path date already passed

Tags: visual-workflow

What happens when a scheduled path date has already passed when the flow is created?  Does nothing happen? Does it happen immediately?

I am working on a new employee flow.  The flow will have a few scheduled paths based on date of hire.  If I want something to happen 14 days before hire but we don't enter the person into the system until week before the hire how can I get the path to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

If the scheduled path date has already passed when record is created then it does happen immediately if the entry conditions are met.

You can test this fairly quickly. If you monitor the time-based workflow queue you will see it scheduled for a date which has already passed and then soon after it will be ran.